# Royal road to Abstract Harmonic Analysis?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, harmonic-analysis, haar-measure

I would like to learn Abstract Harmonic Analysis up to a level where research is feasible.

My plan is the following:

- Read Loomis' book completely again. (I already read all the topics related to Banach Algebras.)
- Read Bachman's Book on the subject.
- Finally study Hewitt's comprehensive book on Abstract Harmonic Analysis.

My interest focuses mainly on Banach Algebras and everything to do with $L^1$ and transforms. I am aware that non-commutative topics are very popular today but I would want to focus on Commutative Harmonic Analysis. Is there any paper or book I should definitely read, or do you have any suggestions on how to continue my study afterwards?

I would be very thankful if you could provide a list of the most interesting papers in the subject (and maybe papers which are not that important but indeed very enlightening).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rudin's "Fourier analysis on groups" and Folland's "A course in abstract harmonic analysis".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rudin's 'Fourier analysis on groups' is one of the most enjoyable books I ever read. How well versed are you in classical harmonic analysis? the books by Katznelson and by Helson go a long way toward motivating the general theory. On the abstract side, Arveson's 'invitation to C^* algebras' is recommended. For the interactions of harmonic analysis and probability, Kahane's "Some random series of functions" is a truly wonderful introduction.

Comment: Hi i know this question is a bit old, but I am also interested in learning abstract harmonic analysis. I was wondering how necessary is classical harmonic analysis? The main reason I find abstract harmonic analysis interesting is the fact that there is a lot of algebra involved whereas classical harmonic analysis is "hard analysis" and it is not easy to find topics (at least at the undergraduate or masters level) where you see both algebra and analysis like this (except for maybe lie groups and differential geomery).

Comment: The motivation for the questions asked in abstract harmonic analysis came from classical harmonic analysis. So some knowledge of classical harmonic analysis will be essential guidance to understand the goals of abstract harmonic analysis.

Comment: Thank you for the reply . I was also wondering , what is the state of research right now in abstract harmonic analysis ? Is it still an active area ?